Is my Fast valid?
I told a person to bring me food from the store but after a while I remembered that i am fasting, and the food is already brought by that person but i did not eat anything. Is my Fast valid?

Your fast would have been valid even if you had eaten the food due to forgetfulness. So why wouldn't it be valid when you didn't even eat it?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. The fast is only broken if you do what breaks the fast, be it eating, drinking or having sexual intercourse while you are aware that you are fasting, actions that you perform without being aware of it are forgiven and valid.
